# Laravel Multidimensional Array to Collection Object Values

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, collections

I have an array that I'm wanting to recursively turn into a collection and to use the collection as object values.

I would like to use the collection object in similar ways that eloquent is used rather than using `$contact['name']` and being able to use `$collection->contacts->each` vs `foreach $collection->contacts .....)`

```
$collection->contacts->each(function ($contact) {
   // ability to use $contact->name (and not have to use $contact['name'])
});
```

Collection Macro:

```
Collection::macro('recursive', function () {
            return $this->map(function ($value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    return (object)$value;
                }

                if (is_object($value)) {
                    return collect($value)->recursive();
                }

                return $value;
            });
        });
```

Example:

```
public function test_it_can_recursively_convert_array_to_collection()
    {
        $data = [
            [
                'name' => 'Michael Scott',
                'emails' => [
                    'mscott@dundermifflin.com',
                    'michaelscarn@dundermifflin.com',
                ],
                'contacts' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Dwight Schrute',
                        'emails' => [
                            'dschrute@dundermifflin.com',
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Jim Halpert',
                        'emails' => [
                            'jhalpert@dundermifflin.com',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $collection = collect($data)->recursive();

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Collection::class, $collection);

        $collection->each(function ($item) {
            $this->assertEquals('Michael Scott', $item->name);
            $item->contacts->each(function ($contact) {
                $this->assertNotNull($contact->name);
            });
        });
    }
```

The original collection map works (e.g. `$collection->each .... $item->name`) but I can't seem to set convert the nested arrays to objects and get the object values.

`Error: Call to a member function each() on array`

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#632
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#13
      +"name": "Michael Scott"
      +"emails": array:2 [
        0 => "mscott@dundermifflin.com"
        1 => "michaelscarn@dundermifflin.com"
      ]
      +"contacts": array:2 [
        0 => array:2 [
          "name" => "Dwight Schrute"
          "emails" => array:1 [
            0 => "dschrute@dundermifflin.com"
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:2 [
          "name" => "Jim Halpert"
          "emails" => array:1 [
            0 => "jhalpert@dundermifflin.com"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @EdwinKrause 6.x

Comment: I played around with your code a bit, but couldn't get it working :-/ . The logic in the Macro seems not to do what it's supposed to... But I don't have time to play more with it. Sorry